# Where does either Bohr or Heisenberg mention the idea of the wave function collapsing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, specific-reference, history, wavefunction-collapse

Could someone reference a paragraph written either by Heisenberg or Bohr where they mention the idea of the [wave function collapsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse)?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse

"The concept of wavefunction collapse was introduced by Werner Heisenberg in his 1927 paper on the uncertainty principle, "Über den anschaulichen Inhalt der quantentheoretischen Kinematic und Mechanik", and incorporated into the mathematical formulation of quantum mechanics by John von Neumann, in his 1932 treatise Mathematische Grundlagen der Quantenmechanik."

Comment: I've looked through Heisenberg's paper and can't find the paragraph: http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19840008978.pdf

Comment: I'm sure that von Neumann's book deals with that idea, maybe you can find some precise reference therein.

Comment: Yes, I think von Neumann's book deals with it, but he wasn't a part of the Copenhagen school. It's claimed in many places that wave function collapse is part of the Copenhagen interpretation and I'd like to know where exactly.

Comment: @LarryHarson : The word collapse is not used, but if you follow the discussion around the formula $(8)$ page $15 (/184)$, it is clearly the idea.